# mongoose delete duplicate docs but not the first one

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I used `findOneAndRemove` to delete duplicate because I knew there was not more than 2 docs with the same "name" value. That would delete the first instance of a doc that has the same "name" value. Now I don't want to delete the first instance. Instead, I want to delete all the other ones. so if there are 3 docs that have the {name: "/face.com"} it should only leave the first one that was added and delete the other 2.

```
Comps.find({}).lean()
    .then(function(comps){
        findDuplicates.getArrayOfNames(comps);
        var dups = findDuplicates.checkForDuplicates();
        //dups is an array of names. It contains a list like ["/face.com", "/example.com"]. those are the ones that are duplicates.
        console.log("DUPS::", dups)

        dups.forEach(function(e){
            var query = {name : e}
            Comps.findOneAndRemove(query, function(err, removed){
                if(err) console.log(err);
                console.log("removed: ", removed)
            })
        })
        console.log("length: ",  comps.length);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log("ERR",err)
    })
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't want to create a unique index on the name field to prevent duplicates from being added in the first place?

Comment: I don't know. I never used it before it. I'm not so advanced in programming and since I'm getting more data I'm thinking of trying it now.

Comment: If I use mongoimport what would happen if I use `unique index`. would I get errors when it is loading? I use mongoimport to upload new docs.

Comment: Yeah it looks like it (See Insert):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--mode